# Removing android permissions to allow autoupdate

Tags: android, google-play

Six months ago, we updated our app from version "A" to version "B." Even six months later, we have people using the old version and giving us bad reviews. Due to the fact that we added new permissions to version B, the app didn't auto update. I came up with the idea of removing the permissions and adding a way to notify users of new versions. This would be version "C." My  question is, will this work? Will the app be automatically updated to version C if I remove permissions to make it match those of version A? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Even if you did that, users might have set Google Play to not auto-update anything anyway and meanwhile you've damaged the user experience for all those people who went to B.

Comment: The additional permissions are only used for push notifications, which we use very lightly. We would be able to add these permissions at a later release.

Comment: Hi @Monarch, did it work? Maybe you can answer your own question with the result.