# Remove Android permissions added in the previous release of the app

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

The previous version of our application added some permissions on the app for recording Audio. Going forward we are not going to be using that feature anymore. So, I wanted to remove all the unused permissions from the manifest file.

How do I do this?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099298/removing-android-permissions-to-allow-autoupdate) question on SO, which is somewhat similar,  but it does not have any answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely remove the permissions which are not required in the latest version, but there is no any specific way to make sure that users would be using your latest version only.

There are some ways to notify them like:

- Sending a push notification about the new version available.
- Force them to update the application, that is like not allowing them to proceed further to use the application. (This is not a good approach!)

If you really want your users to use the latest version then the first way mentioned above is fine, you just need to send push notifications periodically until user updates the app with new version!

Comment: We are ensuring that all the users move towards the latest version. My question is, when we do upgrade, how do I ensure that the Audio permission is not shown on the play store?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava if you remove/add permissions into the manifest file then it would be automatically reflected on play store, but that's for the latest version!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can remove permissions from application and when you will upload latest version, Play store will reflect permission as in new version (means, it will not show permissions which you have removed in new version)
2. You cannot force user to update app, but can ask them to update app by push notification (if you have implemented push notification in previous version)